# Changing standard \ac Acro package behavior when in section, subsection and subsubsections to default to \acl*

Tags: macros, sectioning, acronyms, acro

I want to change how the acro package behaves when used in section headers to default to the long form of the acronym and ignore the use of the acronym, equivalent to `\acl*{GPS}`. I want to do this by default so that you can write `\ac{GPS}` instead of `\acl*{GPS}` every time. Would this be possible?

Code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{sort=true, only-used = true, list-style = extra-tabular, macros=true, list-caps=true, single}
\acsetup{list-short-width=-1cm}
\DeclareAcroListStyle{extra-tabular}{extra-table}{
  table = tabular,  table-spec = lp{12cm}p{2cm}l
}
\newcommand*{\acro}[3]{\DeclareAcronym{#1}{short=#2,long=#3}}

\acro{GPS}{GPS}{Global Positioning Service}

\begin{document}
\ac{GPS}

\section{\acl*{GPS}}

\subsection{\ac{GPS}}

\ac{GPS}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are actually using the `article` class, you can redefine its `\section` command (found in `article.cls`) by adding the following to the preamble (before `\begin{document}`):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\def\ac{\acl*}}}
\makeatother
```